# Which cipher suites are proposed by client and which one chosen by server?

Tags: tls, sniffer, wireshark, cipher-selection

I've sniffed several TLS/SSL communication with Wireshark, and I want to find out which cipher suites are proposed by client and which one chosen by server. How do I do that?

Here you have some of what I have sniffed:
[image]

EDIT:
Here are the first packets:
[image]

Comment: In the bottom pane of wireshark you have the message breakdown, there you can see the *first* negotiation.

Comment: Which one should I click on? I can't see the first negotiation. The first packet has the protocol TCP

Comment: Check the first Client Hello and the first Server Hello.

Comment: Ok, when I do that what should I look at in the message?

Answer (score 1):

The client offers a list of cipher suites in the first message it sends, called [ClientHello](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2).

[image: ClientHello where cipher suites are proposed by client]

The server offers a single ciphersuite it chose from the list offered by the client, in the first message the server sends, called [ServerHello](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.3).

[image: ServerHello where server choses cipher suite]